# Creating and structuring folders in SharePoint

Tags: 2010

I am very new to SharePoint and have been tasked with creating a folder structure within SharePoint and I need help on how to do this.  It appears that the SharePoint I'm using only inserts documents and pages but not folders.  I have been doing some research online and it appears that folders are an option (but not recommended).  Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. I have a "Home" page for a site within our company.  Lets call the site New Jersey.
2. Within "New Jersey" there are counties.  I need folders for each "county" on the New Jersey page.  I don't want to store the individual docs yet because I need further levels of sorting.  Let’s say one of these newly inserted folders is called "Camden County"
3. On the Camden County page, I need more folders for the cities in Camden County.  Voorhees, Cherry Hill, Berlin...etc.  For this, let’s choose Berlin.
4. Finely, on the Berlin page, I can deposit the documents I need.

This file structure is important because the documents I'm uploading are specific to Berlin but adding all of the "City" level folders on the New Jersey page would be too overwhelming.  The documents I'm uploading are very specific (down to a person).

Please help.

Mike

Comment: Is this a one-time task?  Are all of the documents going in one Document Library, just organized into your sub-folders?  Do you have access to the SharePoint server itself (allowing you to use PowerShell on the server)?

Answer (score 1):

You can Create Such folder Structure on your hard Disk and Use Powershell to Import all of them To Specific Document Library.

```
if((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell") -eq $null)
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
}

#Script settings

$webUrl = "http://XYZ:310/"

$docLibraryName = "Documents"
$docLibraryUrlName = "Shared Documents"

$localFolderPath = "C:\\FolderName"

#Open web and library

$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl

$docLibrary = $web.Lists[$docLibraryName]

$files = ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo] (Get-Item $localFolderPath)).GetFiles()

ForEach($file in $files)
{

    #Open file
    $fileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $file.FullName)).OpenRead()

    #Add file
    $folder =  $web.getfolder($docLibraryUrlName)

    write-host "Copying file " $file.Name " to " $folder.ServerRelativeUrl "..."
    $spFile = $folder.Files.Add($folder.Url + "/" + $file.Name, [System.IO.Stream]$fileStream, $true)
    write-host "Success"

    #Close file stream
    $fileStream.Close();
}

#Dispose web

$web.Dispose()
```